# Multiple Database with different entities in Room DB

Tags: android, android-room

I am using ROOM db in my Android application. I am creating multiple DB in runtime,but i am facing difficulty maintaining different tables for these runtime databases. Is it possible to do this in ROOM db?

````
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

    companion object {
        private var mInstance: AppDatabase? = null


        @Synchronized
        fun getInstance(dbName: String): AppDatabase {
            if (mInstance == null)
                mInstance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    OrbiApp.instance.applicationContext, AppDatabase::class.java,
                    dbName
                )
                    .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                    .addCallback(roomCallback)
                    .build()

            return mInstance!!

        }
} ```
````

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to do this in ROOM db?

Yes, **BUT** using a single `@Database` annotated class, as you you have, then if the tables are ***different***, then you would need to include all of the tables in the list of entities defined by the @Database annotation, so the **different** tables are accessible irrespective of the intended database.

You also have the issue of the single instance, so if you were to use `getInstance` on a subsequent invocation, even if the database name were different then it would simply return the first database.

For example if you had:-

```
@Entity
data class T1(
    @PrimaryKey
    val id: Long?=null,
    val name: String
)
@Entity
data class T2(
    @PrimaryKey
    val id: Long?=null,
    val description: String
)
@Dao
interface AllDao {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun insert(t1: T1): Long
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun insert(t2: T2)

    fun insert(valueToInsert: String, dbName: String ) {
        when (dbName) {
            "DB1" -> insert(T1(name = valueToInsert))
            "DB2" -> insert(T2(description = valueToInsert))
        }
    }
}
@Database(entities = [T1::class,T2::class], exportSchema = false, version = 1)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun getAllDao(): AllDao

    companion object {
        private var mInstance: AppDatabase? = null
        @Synchronized
        fun getInstance(context: Context, dbName: String): AppDatabase {
            if (mInstance == null)
                mInstance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context, AppDatabase::class.java,
                    dbName
                )
                    .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                    .allowMainThreadQueries() /* For brevity of demo */
                    .addCallback(roomCallback)
                    .build()
            return mInstance!!
        }
        
        val roomCallback= object: Callback(){
        }
    }
}
```

along with:-

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var db1: AppDatabase
    lateinit var db2: AppDatabase
    lateinit var daoDB1: AllDao
    lateinit var daoDB2: AllDao
    val db1Name = "DB1"
    val db2Name = "DB2"
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        db1 = AppDatabase.getInstance(this,db1Name)
        db2 = AppDatabase.getInstance(this,db2Name)
        daoDB1 = db1.getAllDao()
        daoDB2 = db2.getAllDao()

        daoDB1.insert("value for T1 in DB1",db1Name)
        daoDB2.insert("value for T2 in DB2",db2Name)
    }
}
```

The the result would be a single database **DB1** but with rows inserted into the ***different*** tables as the attempt to get and instance of **DB2** returns **DB1**. e.g.

[image]

Perhaps this is where you are having issues. You would need to differentiate between the instances.

To further demonstrate consider the following (changes to the getInstance function + new buildDB function):-

```
@Database(entities = [T1::class,T2::class], exportSchema = false, version = 1)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun getAllDao(): AllDao

    companion object {
        private var mInstanceDB1: AppDatabase?=null
        private var mInstanceDB2: AppDatabase?=null
        @Synchronized
        fun getInstance(context: Context, dbName: String): AppDatabase {
            if (dbName == "DB1") {
                if (mInstanceDB1==null) {
                    mInstanceDB1 = buildDB(context,dbName)
                }
                return mInstanceDB1 as AppDatabase
            } else {
                if (mInstanceDB2==null) {
                    mInstanceDB2 = buildDB(context,dbName)
                }
                return mInstanceDB2 as AppDatabase
            }
        }
        private fun buildDB(context: Context, dbName: String): AppDatabase {
            return Room.databaseBuilder(context,AppDatabase::class.java,dbName)
                .allowMainThreadQueries().addCallback(roomCallback).build()
        }

        val roomCallback= object: Callback(){
        }
    }
}
```

Without any other changes and rerunning the App, then:-

For DB1:-

[image]

- pre-existing rows remain, 1 row (not 2 this time) added to T1
- DB2 can be seen to exist

and for DB2:-

[image]